# Can iPhone function as Web Cam?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios

I have a MacPro 2010, still going strong. Given the need to access online web conferences, I've been using an iPad. I’d like to plug a phone via USB and somehow have it recognised as the mic/video input.

- Yosemite on the Mac
- iOS 13 on the iPhone 8+

Is there any way to use the iPhone to function as a web-cam?

Edit: Given the current events, webcams appear to be out of stock. This was the reason for this question. Meanwhile, I've recommissioned an old MacBook that had been replace when the kid went off to college.